# Primefaces p:treeNode background colour

Tags: primefaces, tree, treenode

I have a sidebar which contains a primefaces `p:tree` element. Here is it:

```
<p:tree value="#{sidebarSelectionView.systemRoot}"
               var="treeNodeDescriptor"
               selectionMode="single"
               selection="#{sidebarSelectionView.selectedNode}">
    <p:ajax event="select" update=":unitContentId" />
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
       <h:outputText value="#{treeNodeDescriptor.name}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

The tree node consists of many nested nodes. Each leaf node is associated with a content page wich is displayed if the node is selected.

The generated tree seems like this:

```
Agent
    customer1
        subcustomer1
        subcustomer2
```

How can I make the nodes `Agent, customer1` and `subcustomer1` to have say red background colour, if the content page associated with the `subcustomer1` changes its internal state? The internal state is checked by `<p:poll>`.

Comment: Did my answer help in any way? If not what was wrong and how can i improve? Please leave a comment, accept or vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to store your page states in the backing bean when polled, e.g. in a nodedata-state-map. Just use your right classes.

```java
public class SidebarSelectionView {

  private Map<[NodedataClass], [StateClass]> nodedataStateMap;

  ...
}
```

With that you are able to style your nodes with

```xml
<h:outputText
  value="#{treeNodeDescriptor.name}" 
  style="background-color: ##{sidebarSelectionView.nodedataStateMap[treeNodeDescriptor].stateName eq 'bad' ? 'FF0000' : '00FF00'};"
/>
```

or use custom style classes with

```xml
<h:outputText
  value="#{treeNodeDescriptor.name}"
  styleClass="#{sidebarSelectionView.nodedataStateMap[treeNodeDescriptor].stateName eq 'bad' ? 'stateBad' : 'stateGood'}"
/>
```

Example assumes a *StateClass* with a *stateName* property of type *String*. Just adapt to your state class. I hope you got the idea.

Don´t forget to update your tree with

```xml
<p:poll update="treeId" />
```

to reflect state changes.